# Why all images disapear from my page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

IIS 8. Windows Server 2012. Build 9200.

I made MVC 4 .NET project and published it. When you first load the site, you can see page with all images, with styles etc. But after few full reloads (F5) all these my resources have disappearing! I can see only text, but no styles, no images.

Explain me please what am I doing wrong?=(

Comment: First step is to use suitable tools (e.g. IE Developer Tools, Fiddler, Firebug, etc) to see whether the browser is still *requesting* these resources, and if it is, to see what *responses* are coming back from the server. Once you have that information, if you're not enlightened by it yourself, please add that information to your question. At the moment, it would just be a guessing game, with too many possibilities.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have see the network tab in developer tools (google chrome) and found a lot of my resources with status-code 304. But all these files have been loaded. After refresh most files got status code 404 and did not load. And receiving time is awfully big...  -134983745290375... ms